# addObjectsFromArray returns error

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I am trying to use the addObjectsFromArray to "concatenate" (so to speak) two arrays together. Here is an overview of the code:

```
NSArray *fixed = [NSArray arrayWithArray:timeline2];
NSLog(@"Made the temp successfully.Contents: %@", fixed);

[arrayOfNewsItems addObjectsFromArray:fixed];
```

The Log statement can confirm that there is valid data in the "fixed" and "timeline2" arrays, and earlier in the program, I confirmed that data exists in the "arrayOfNewsItems" array.

The exception I receive after the attempt at addObjects.. is this:

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
```

arrayOfNewsItems is a NSMutableArray. It's a property. Actually, it's declared like this:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray * arrayOfNewsItems;
```

Perhaps it's the "nonatomic" statement? I don't fully understand these either.

The only thing I can think of is that the array elements in each array have different object types - or rather, although they are each arrays of dictionary objects, the objects themselves consist of a different list of key/value pairs. For example:

Array element 1 might contain:

```
(key)                 (value)
name                   Joe
title                  Mr.
```

And Array element 2 might contain:

```
(key)                 (value)
phone                 555-1263
shoeSize              2
```

Now, in any other language, I would never try this, but I'm pretty sure I was told in an earlier post that this was OK to do. I understand that objective-c stores them as (id), and we can mash everything in there together like that. So, the questions are:

- Is this true?
- If so, what have I missed?

I would to get a solid answer on this, before I start coding a function to make all field names the same for the final array.

I would certainly appreciate any and all help I can get! Thanks.

Comment: I see "key" and "value" there but you are talking about arrays and not dictionaries.  Are the items in the array "`NSDictionary`" objects or what are they?

Comment: Where do you set `arrayOfNewsItems`?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII that's just where I think the mistake is, too. See my answer ;)

Comment: Did you search S.O. for "mutating method sent to immutable object" to see if those Q&As help at all?

Comment: The array is an array of dictionaries, which I mention in my post, but I should have specified in my example: "Array1 *element* 1", and "Array2 *element* 1". It is initialized in another function, during the viewController's load.

Comment: Have you tried defining `fixed` as `NSMutableArray`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's pretty clear: `mutating method sent to immutable object`
This means that you have an **immutable** instance of `NSArray`.

Even though it is defined as `NSMutableArray`, it doesn't mean that it really is one. It only removes the warnings when trying to call mutating methods like `-addObjectsFromArray:`.

You have to make sure that when creating the array, you send alloc/init to the **mutable** version:

```
self.arrayOfNewsItems = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Comment: Even if it's a property, I have to alloc and init before internal use?

Comment: I just checked, and I did init the array as mutable, earlier on, using: arrayOfNewsItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  -- it was in a different function, though.

Comment: That's just impossible. Can you maybe host your whole project on GitHub and share the link? Also, try logging `[self.arrayOfNewsItems class]`.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are saying. What part of what I have said is impossible, in your opinion? I don't profess to be an expert by any means - but I assure you, it is not my intention to make any false claims. At this time I don't feel comfortable releasing the entire project. Now, moving forward, I can provide an update by saying that I changed the array to simply an instance variable, and I'm still getting the same error. Also - I don't know how to use the ...class method you provided. What's it for? I'm using ARC, by the way, so the autorelease is forbidden.

Comment: It is simply impossible that you instantiate a mutable version and get the error mentioned above. If you don't share code, I won't be able to help you.

Comment: The way it is now, after the viewController loads, the user clicks a button. The button is attached to a modal segue on the storyboard, so the method that runs is here:

Comment: Is where? Did you forget to paste the link?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lxcZYF8-1yZhC0DbCKl65kSiFSfL-SO-mvIh-gp9GDM/edit

Comment: Just as I said, it is an immutable instance. `arrayOfNewsItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 arrayOfNewsItems = [valueFieldOnly objectForKey:@"items"];` This overwrites the old value, destroys any reference to it and therefore leaks memory. Also the new value (`[valueFieldOnly objectForKey:@"items"];`) is immutable, try calling `-mutableCopy` on it.